# How do I get one value from a duplicate name?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Situation:** I have a list of classes in a list view. It's working fine. I am able to retrieve the classes in a list like this:

```
English
Math
French
```

This is the database of classes:

[image]

Now, when clicking on a list item, I want to show the section of that class, so when I click on the `English` list item, an alert dialog should show with the section of that class. I am able to do that like this:

```
listclasses.setLongClickable(true);

listclasses.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final String selectedFromList = (String) listclasses.getItemAtPosition(position);
        final DatabaseReference retrieve = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Class");
        retriev.orderByChild("Classname").equalTo(selectedFromList).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    String key=data.getKey();

                    DatabaseReference referes=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Class");
                    referes.orderByKey().equalTo(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                            String section=datas.child("section").getValue().toString();

                            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(StudentSearchActivity.this); //inflate converts xml to a view object to use in code
                            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.info, null); //two parameters, the xml and the root(null means the layout is a child of viewgroup

                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    StudentSearchActivity.this); /*alertdialog.builder class,creates a builder for alert dialog, parameter is context */

                            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
                            final TextView sections = (TextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.sections);
                            sections.setText(section);
                            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true); //true can be canceled with back key
                            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); //creates alert dialog from builder
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }}
```

**Problem:** When I have the same class name example `English` but each one is in a section, I get the section of both on long click of an item. Example:

Step 1: long click on `English` item.

Step 2: alert dialog with section:503 appears.

Step 3: on back pressed or on `ok` pressed, another alert dialog with section:402 appears.

So both sections are appearing on long click of one class since it's the same name, but this is wrong. Only the section of that English class should appear, then when clicking on the other English class, also the section of this English class should appear only. Can this be solved in Firebase?

I'm using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and also in the database it is `Classname` as in the code.

Comment: So what you want to do on such case?

Comment: Im asking if it can be solved?  And how? I just want on long click on the duplicate  name to show its section and not both

Comment: To show only one "English" in list???

Comment: No read the question again please,  i have two classes called English each class has a different section. On click of a class i want its section to show but since its the same name im getting both sections when clicking on English. Check the steps and question again

Comment: I understand your question. But I want to know what your expected result. Either you want different English items on list on which individual section popup will show or you want single popup with both section combined

Comment: The popup is working.  It doesnt work when there are two classes with the same name. What I want is on long click of English the popup that contains the section of English to appear.  Then on long click of the second English the popup that contains the section of this English class should appear.  Currently,  on Long click on class English BOTH sections are appearing and that is wrong!!

Comment: @ankitpatidar I just wanted to have two english classes in the list with the name english, but it seems this does not work and thus I have to change one class to english1 and another keep it as english

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you hardcoded the `listclasses`'s value and then using the value to query one of the `Class` which is why you might get multiple children. It's because there are two childs which contains the same value for the `classname` based on your screenshot.

You have to attach a listener to the `Class` node and then populate the `listclasses` based on the database's value, and then set the `OnClickListener` or `OnLongItemClickListener` to each one of them that shows an `AlertDialog` with their own `section` value.

Here's the solution

```
// to store the class's value
List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<>();

// to retrieve the list of class from the database
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Class");
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Class class = dataSnapshot.getValue(Class.class);
        classes.add(class);

        ... add 'class.getClassName()' to the listclasses adapter
    }
});

// add the OnItemLongClickListener
listclasses.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView <<?>parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Class selectedClass = classes.get(position);

        ... show an AlertDialog with the value of 'selectedClass.getSection()'
    }
});
```

Comment: thats what im doing, im populating the `listclasses` from the database but Im not using a model class, so im doing String classnames=dataSnapshot.child("Classname").getValue().toString(); and then listofclasses.add(classnames);